# [1581474671.669][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Since upgrading my selenium/chrome today, I've been getting the following error in my Console while using Selenium Chromedriver.

> [1581474671.669][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100

I've done a lot of digging, and tried many solutions suggested by Stackoverflow. Including adding all of the following

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("ignore-certificate-errors");
options.AddArguments("start-maximized");
options.AddArguments("enable-automation");
options.AddArguments("--headless");
options.AddArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.AddArguments("--disable-infobars");
options.AddArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
options.AddArguments("--disable-browser-side-navigation");
options.AddArguments("--disable-gpu");
var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Most notably, `--disable-gpu` supposedly fixes the issue, but this isn't the case.

I am running Selenium Chromedriver version: 80.0.3987.1600.

Comment: Duplicate, I think: stackoverflow.com/questions/60114639 .

Comment: Just downgrade to older version for now if you are doing some urgent work and need a quick fix should work.

Comment: @confusedMind That has worked, thank you! Still curious as to what the issue is with the new version though